# Sum of a product of measures of singletons

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

The following is from Durretts Probability Theory and Examples, question 1.7.3 part (ii).

> Let $F$, $G$ be Stieltjes measure functions, and let $\mu$, $\nu$ be the corresponding measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{R})$. Show that
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{(a,b]} F(y) \, dG(y) +\int_{(a,b]} G(y) \, dF(y) = F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a) + \sum_{x\in(a, b]} \mu(\{x\})\nu(\{x\})
> \end{align}

The problem is that I have no idea how to interpret the second term on the right. What is $\mu(\{x\})$? $\nu(\{x\})$?

Some further information: as a remark on the second term, Durrett says:

> To see that the second term is needed, let $F(x)=G(x)=\mathrm{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ and $a<0<b$.

In addition, to solve this question I think you need to use the result that
\begin{align*}
\int_{(a, b]} \{ F(y) -F(a)\} \, dG(y) = (\mu \times \nu)(\{(x,y): a<x\leq y\leq b\})
\end{align*}
but I could be wrong...

Any help with interpretation would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution or just interpretation? If just interpretation, what specifically about $\mu(\{x\})$ is giving you difficulty? Is it how the stieltjes measure function induces a measure on $\mathbb{R}$? The remark he gives is saying that the measure of a singleton under the induced measure will be nonzero when the inducing stieltjes function has a discontinuity at the point in the singleton. So you need to account for it in the formula.

Comment: @snarfblaat I am looking for an interpretation. I suppose my problem is that I do not understand how the singleton can have non-zero measure. In addition, I do not know what the term $\sum_{x \in (a,b]} \mu(\{x\})\nu(\{x\})$ represents. I.e. assuming that the singletons have non-zero measure, why could this term not be written $\mu((a,b])\nu((a,b])$? Although interpretation is preferable, I understand it may be that the best explanation comes from partially solving the problem...

Comment: The obvious analogy is probability, with distributions which are a mixture of  continuous and discrete and $\sum_x \mu(\{x\})\nu(\{x\})$ corresponds to something like $\sum_x \mathbb{P}(Y=x)\mathbb{P}(Z=x)$ to pick up the discrete coincidences

Comment: Take his example $F=\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty]}$, then $\mu(\{0\})=_{def}\inf_{a,b\mid x\in (a,b)}\{F(b)-F(a)\}=1,$ since $F(x)$ is 1 for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$ Even if $\mu$ were completely discrete, $\sum\mu(\{x\})\nu(\{x\})$ will differ from $\mu((a,b])\nu((a,b])$ for the same reason $(u_1+u_2+\ldots)(v_1+v_2+\ldots)$ differs from $u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\ldots$.

Comment: @snarfblaat Thank you for your answer, I understand now